# how to push a html button (input tag) as a json object in json array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a json array now I want to push one json object to it which is a html button

```
<input type="submit"  class="btn-primary" onclick="notifications('YES')" value="Yes"/> 
<input type="submit"  class="btn-primary"  onclick="notifications('NO')"   value="No" />
```

But Iam unable to add to json array it is giving me Unexpected String error.So how can I psuh this whole to a json array using javascript

Comment: Can you show us what code you have? Also, welcome to stackoverflow! Consider reading this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I believe there is some fundamental misunderstanding between javascript and html. It looks like you are trying to add an html component to a javascript array. what is your goal and what is your exact code trying to do?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you need to escape quotes like this

```js
var btn1= '<input type="submit"  class="btn-primary" onclick="notifications(\'YES\')" value="Yes"/>';
var btn2 = '<input type="submit"  class="btn-primary"  onclick="notifications(\'NO\')"   value="No" />';
var all = {btn1,btn2};
console.log(all);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.btn').click(function(e){
   var tagVal = $(e.target);
   console.log(tagVal["0"]);
   console.log(tagVal["0"].value);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Yes"/>
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="No" />
```